# Bootstrap. Prepended and appended input. How to max input field width?

Tags: input, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap from twitter. What I want is to make a prepended text, and input field and a button, but I want my input field have the max available width so that the right edge of the submit button was near the right edge of the well. From the bootstrap documentation there is the **.input-block-level** class that lets any  or  element behave like a block level element, but applying it to the input gives in result the central input the size of the well. http://jsfiddle.net/Uc4CE/

```
<div class="well">
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
  <span class="add-on">Some text</span>
  <input class="input" type="text" name="xxx" value="xxx" />
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="xxx" />
  <input type="submit" value="xx" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was looking for something similar and this solution from https://gist.github.com/mattjorn/5020957 worked for me - add `.input-block-level` to your outer div, e.g.,

`<div class="input-prepend input-append input-block-level">`

and then extend the bootstrap CSS like this:

```
.input-prepend.input-block-level {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-prepend.input-block-level .add-on {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: white;
}

.input-prepend.input-block-level > input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  border-left-style: none;
}
```

Comment: i used this but put a set width for the .add-on{} of 30px. I know this is not the best solution given it will break on different content in the add on section but looks good for just an icon.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT : Please note, that this answer is valid for Bootstrap v2.3.x. Bootstrap 3 already solves this natively ([see doc](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)).**

Inspired by A lee's answer, here is my kinda **improved solution** (includes both append and prepend, minimum possible add-on width, removed unnecessary styles, auto height...). Include this after Bootstrap CSS/LESS files:

```css
.input-append.input-block-level,
.input-prepend.input-block-level {
  display: table;
}

.input-append.input-block-level .add-on,
.input-prepend.input-block-level .add-on {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%; /* remove this if you want default bootstrap button width */
}

.input-append.input-block-level > input,
.input-prepend.input-block-level > input {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* use bootstrap mixin or include vendor variants */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* for Firefox */
  display: table; /* table-cell is not working well in Chrome for small widths */
  min-height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-append.input-block-level > input {
  border-right: 0;
}

.input-prepend.input-block-level > input {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

Use it like this in your HTML and remember, **you have to use `a` tags** not `button` for your buttons in this case:

```html
<div class="input-append input-block-level">
  <input type="text" />
  <a class="btn add-on">click</a>
</div>
```

**Edit:** In IE8, if you set `display: table` in `.input-append.input-block-level > input`, the input tag becomes uneditable despite taking focus.

Completely omitting this `display:` parameter makes it work as expected in IE8 as well as current Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

Comment: Awesome, that sorted it for me

Comment: This worked better than the accepted solution for me. Accepted solution didn't resize right.

Answer (score 3):

may be use for `div class="input-prepend input-append"` additional style `margin-right`

result for your code:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="input-prepend input-append" style="margin-right: 108px;">
        <span class="add-on">Some text</span>
        <input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="xxx" value="xxx" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="xxx" />
        <input type="submit" value="xx" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uc4CE/1/

Comment: not the best solution since the letter quantity in the last button differs for different language and therefore not acceptable, unfortunately.

Comment: Another option I have not found in my project.

Width of the last button can be count and through a script to add the required margin-right

Comment: I had the same idea, a well as to define a fixed width of a button, a bit larger, to be able to hold the text on every language.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for this in the 3.0 branch of Twitter Bootstrap as per [@mdo's comment on this issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6414).

However, I use the following javascript in my projects in the meantime when I output a `django-crispy forms` layout within a `<div class="span4">`. This accounts for responsive designs.

---

**example HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        {% crispy form %}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**style.css**

```
/* I also set this to account for smaller widtsh */

form fieldset {
    width:100%
}
```

---

**fix.js**

***NOTE: I trigger this with window resizings as well.***

> function sizeInputs() {
>   var fw = $('form fieldset').innerWidth();
>   $('form .input-prepend').each(function(){
>       $(this).children('input').css('width', fw-$(this).children('.add-on').innerWidth());   }); };
>
> $(document).ready(function() {   sizeInputs(); });
>
> $(window).resize(function() {   sizeInputs(); });